# Preserving zero length groups with aggregate

Tags: r, aggregate

I just noticed that aggregate disappears empty groups from the result, how can I solve this? e.g.

```
`xx <- c("a", "b", "d", "a", "d", "a")
 xx <- factor(xx, levels = c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
 y <- rnorm(60, 5, 1)
 z <- matrix(y, 6, 10)
 aggregate(z, by = list(groups = xx), sum)`
```

`xx` is a factor variable with 4 levels, but the result gives just 3 rows, and would like a row for the `"c"` level with zeros. I would like the same behavior of `table(xx)` tha gives frecuencies even for levels with no observations.

Comment: Maybe try `by(z, xx, colSums)` as an alternative to `aggregate`.

Answer (score 2):

We can create another `data.frame` with just the `levels` of 'xx' and then `merge` with the `aggregate`.  The output will have all the 'groups' while the row corresponding to the missing level for the other columns will be NA.

```
merge(data.frame(groups=levels(xx)),
   aggregate(z, by = list(groups = xx), sum), all.x=TRUE)
```

---

Another option might be to convert to 'long' format with `melt` and then use `dcast` with `fun.aggregate` as 'sum' and `drop=FALSE`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(data.table(groups=xx, z), id.var='groups'), 
         groups~variable, value.var='value', sum, drop=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since R 3.5.0, the new parameter "drop" was added,
Hence, use following code

```
 aggregate(z, by = list(groups = xx), sum,drop=F)
```

The unused combination will be shown.